# building monodevelop with visual studio 2017

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I try to build monodevelop on windows 10 with visual studio 2017 community
Done everything as https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/ says.

I get lot of errors though, mainly becasuse references are not resolved.

When I do following
Open project properties in Visual STudio
go to reference paths
add reference paths e.g.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\atk\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\glade\

I get references ok for one project.

But there are many-many projects in this solution.

How feed those paths to  solution/all projects so 
that all dll references would get solved automatically?

Comment: Did you install the dependencies listed on the [monodevelop page](https://github.com/mono/md-website/blob/gh-pages/developers/building-monodevelop.md#prerequisites-and-source)? I usually build monodevelop on Windows 10 from the command line using the winbuild.bat file.